# Cannot connect my sim card to internet

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, mobile-broadband

I've got a problem with the connection to internet with mobile broadband. I first checked that the Sim Card is functioning with Windows (connection was good). Then I installed the newest Kubuntu (18.10) and now I can't get the internet connection.

The sim card is recognized by the system (I can even receive SMS), but is not connecting to the internet.

Those are generic instruction for the connection from my mobile provider:

> Under Name, enter Salt Internet.
>
> Under APN, enter internet.
>
> Under Proxy, enter nothing
>
> Under Port, enter nothing
>
> Under Username, enter nothing
>
> Under Password, enter nothing
>
> Under MCC, enter 228
>
> Under MNC, enter 03
>
> Under Authentication type, tick PAP.
>
> Choose APN type. If this screen appears, enter default,supl. If this screen does not appear, tick Internet and choose OK.

With the standard connection tool I cannot enter all these options (only name and APN) and, after configuring it, it tries to connect but after a while it gives up.

Do you have any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this via a modem?

Answer (score 0):

it is integrated in a Fujitzu Lifebook. I deselected all authentication methods (EAP, MSCHAP, MSCHAPv2 and CHAP) and the only one I left selected is PAP. I did an update and a reboot now it is working!

Sorry for disturbing you, I hope this answer can help someone.